# Can variable templates infer type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-deduction, variable-templates

[c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) introduced [variable templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) so I can do:

```
template <typename T>
const auto PI = std::acos(static_cast<T>(-1));
```

Now, when using this variable can the type be deduced? For example:

```
const auto TWO_PI = 2.0F * PI;
```

Here I would expect `PI<float>` it seems like the compiler should be able to deduce that. Why won't the compiler select this for me?

Comment: Why do you expect float deduction ?

Comment: No idea why you believe PI should be float.

Comment: @Jarod42 Cause it's multiplied by a `float`?

Comment: @SergeyA Cause it's multiplied by a `float`?

Comment: So the compiler should randomly look around at subexpressions and pick *something* if possible? How's that useful behavior?

Comment: and for `template <std::size_t N> std::size_t Fact();` you expect in `5 * Fact()` `N` is deduced as 5 ? :)

Comment: @Jarod42 No an you're talking about a function, which *is* deduced by what's passed to it.

Comment: Well, so what? Even if I take your line of thinking (I am still unsure how compiler is expected to deduce the type), still float could be multiplied by multiple different types. Why single out float? However, it is all bizarre. Alleged relationship between template argument of template variable and type of the variable is still beyond me.

Comment: @SergeyA So I think a good example of this would be: `min(1L, 0.0F)` this is ambiguous. You'd have to cast to the same type, or explicitly specify the `min` template you are using. So for example: `min(static_cast<float>(1L), 0.0F)` It makes me sad that you don't see how this directly corresponds to something like `1L * PI * 0.0F`. It's ambiguous in the *exact* same way. You'd need to cast so it was clear which version of `PI` you were using or explicitly specify the template. So for example: `static_cast<float>(1L) * PI * 0.0F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### No, it's not possible.*

---

*There is an ugly alternative, but I'd advise against using it:

```
template <typename T> const auto pi = std::acos(static_cast<T>(-1));

struct auto_pi_t {} auto_pi;

template <typename T> auto operator+(T a, auto_pi_t)
{return a + pi<std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T, double>>;}
template <typename T> auto operator+(auto_pi_t, T a)
{return pi<std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T, double>> + a;}
// For similar overloads for all plausible operators.
```